# Increase import fom trade ports's freight rail terminal

Tags: simcity-2013

I'm trying to ditch mining for importing. Since my roads are already taxed enough, I want to import through rail station.
Raw ore imports are however not even close to filling the demand.
No matter how many lots I build, it just imports 120 tons of raw ore per day.

How can I increase the imported amount of raw ore over rail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each method of importing has a maximum quantity that can be imported per delivery. For example;

- freight trains can import two shipments of cargo (20 tons of metal/alloy etc or 20,000 barrels of oil) in each of their freight cars, with up to a  maximum of six freight cars per train
- cargo ships have a capacity of 20 shipments, which equates to 200 tons of metal/alloy/etc or 200,000 barrels of oil, however each cargo ship can only import and export one type of resource at a time so it is recommended to build dedicated Trade Ports for each resource

Therefore, to increase the maximum amount of resources you can import/export at a time, you will need to build additional Trade Ports.